# Why is my ListView laggy on newer devices, but fast on older devices?

Tags: android

So I am doing the typical listview viewholder pattern.  I am also setting images in a background thread and disabling loading images if the user flings the list.

On older devices (Galaxy s, htc desire, Original Google nexus) my listview works perfectly, no lag at all, even when i scroll/fling the listview. However, on my newer devices (Galaxy S3, Nexus) it is super laggy.

I am performing quite a bit of if/else conditions to setvisibility on certain views. Can this be the root cause? If so why would it be only affecting newer devices?

Comment: Is it possible that your phone is connected to your PC over USB, while you are scrolling

Comment: Lol? Yes, but this happens even when it is not connected to my PC...

Comment: Okay I got a problem like that with a defy before, but only when it is connected

Comment: Is it specific to newer devices or to newer versions of Android?

Comment: Seems like just new devices.  It works well on my galaxy s2 with 4.1.

Comment: Are you using AsyncTask to load the images?

Comment: @HAxxor I am getting the exact same problem.  Scrolling the ListView on our Nexus devices is horrendous, but is perfectly smooth on the old Galaxy Ace we have.  My ListView rows are just two TextViews.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing your code. Try hooking the device up to adb, open DDMS and press the method profiling button (icon with 3 arrows and a red dot), then start scrolling a bunch for a few seconds in your app. Press the stop profiling button (same button) and [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) will open and you see what is using up all the CPU time.